# Как автоматизировать подстановку FK в PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Делаю файл `populate.sql`, который будет использоваться для заполнения базы данных *(PostgreSQL)* тестовыми значениями. В базе очень много таблиц и различных связей, поэтому делать тестовые значение непросто. Вот для примера кусок `populate.sql`:

```
INSERT INTO themes(name)
VALUES ('Математика'),
       ('Русский язык');

INSERT INTO paragraphs(name, theme_id)
VALUES ('Операции с дробями', 100002);
```

Сначала я создаю запись в `theme`, потом создаю запись в `paragraphs`, которая ссылается на `theme`. Причём вот здесь: `('Операции с дробями', 100002)` я вынужден вручную прописывать FK.

Теперь представим, что я позже захотел добавить в тестовые данные ещё одну тему:

```
INSERT INTO themes(name)
VALUES ('Математика'),
       ('Русский язык'),
       ('Обществознание');

INSERT INTO paragraphs(name, theme_id)
VALUES ('Операции с дробями', 100002);
```

И теперь мне надо вручную поменять FK с 100002 на 100003. Причём в базе данных всего 21 таблица, связей очень много, и на каждое небольшое изменение будет уходить не менее получаса.

Я хочу автоматизировать процесс подстановки FK, сделать что-то вроде такого:

```
INSERT INTO paragraphs(name, theme_id)
VALUES ('Операции с дробями', (SELECT themes.id FROM themes WHERE themes.name = 'Математика'));
```

но это не работает. Или мне надо каким-то образом сохранять нужный мне FK в переменную, чтобы потом использовать её несколько раз и менять только в одном месте.

Как я могу решить данную проблему?

Comment: `но это не работает` поясните какую именно вы видите ошибку. Потому что это - работает.

Comment: @Мелкий премного извиняюсь, это работает действительно, а ошибка там по другой причине была... Видите ли, я просто пытаюсь найти оптимальный способ. Делать такой селект для получения FK - оптимально? Или может быть можно сделать что-то вроде переменной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, используя функции. Моя функция принимает имя `theme` и возвращает соответствующий id.

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_theme_id(VARCHAR) RETURNS INTEGER AS
'SELECT themes.id
 FROM themes
 WHERE themes.name = $1' LANGUAGE sql;
```

В скобках указывается тип принимаемого значения. После `RETURNS` указывается тип возвращаемого значения, а внутри апострофов размещено тело функции. Теперь я получаю FK таким образом:

```
INSERT INTO paragraphs(name, theme_id)
VALUES ('Операции с дробями', get_theme_id('Математика'));
```

---

Я решил не использовать PL/PgSQL потому что оператор RETURNING возвращает ошибку, если пытаться обработать более одной строки. Поэтому вот это работает:

```
INSERT INTO themes(name)
    VALUES ('Математика')
    RETURNING id INTO running_id;
```

но вот это уже не работает:

```
INSERT INTO themes(name)
        VALUES ('Математика'),
               ('Русский язык')
        RETURNING id, id INTO math_id, rus_lang_id;
```

На самом деле существует возможность заставлять RETURNING обрабатывать несколько значений, но моего уровня в SQL оказалось недостаточно для того, чтобы разобраться с этим. Решение заключается в использование массивов или что-то в этом роде - я не стал с этим разбираться, так как мне нерационально тратить время на поиски более правильного решение, тогда как функции вполне решают мою проблему. Просто предупреждаю, что **RETURNING может обрабатывать несколько значений**!

Answer (score 2):

Лучше исползуйте `returning` clause. Пример на pl/pgsql:

```sql
do language plpgsql
$$
declare
  running_id integer;
begin
  INSERT INTO themes(name)
    VALUES ('Математика')
    RETURNING id INTO running_id ;

  INSERT INTO paragraphs(name, theme_id)
    VALUES ('Операции с дробями', running_id);
end;
$$;
```

Comment: Интересный вариант. Но если я хочу несколько строк вставить, то неудобно, для каждой строки надо INSERT INTO table прописывать отдельно, потому что RETURNING только одно значение может обработать. Как-то можно сразу несколько значений записывать?